# quarkus with application managed persistence

Tags: quarkus

Actually, I use WildFly JEE Server and consider to switch to Quarkus. I have the following questions about quarkus:

**1. persistence.xml**

I see that quarkus uses its own `application.properties` to set up database. Can I use `persistence.xml` instead?

**2. container managed persistence**

Does quarkus provide something similar or must I manage persistence by myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your question around *Container Manager Persistence*;

- You can mark any bean method with the standard `@Transactional` annotation.
- The Transaction Manager is automatically setup and configured with reasonable defaults; see the [Transactions Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction) to reconfigure.
- The Datasource (connection pool) is integrated with the Transaction Manager, and optionally allows for XA. See [Datasource Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#quarkus-agroal_quarkus.datasource.transactions)
- Hibernate ORM is integrated with all of the above automatically - it's effectively running in "JTA Mode"
- You can use CDI's standard `@Inject` to get an `EntityManager`
- or you can use [Hibernate ORM with Panache](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache) to not even need an EntityManager :-) It will still bind to the transactional components.

If you don't like how this is integrated for you, or just prefer old-style configuration, you can use the [configuration via `persistence.xml`](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#setting-up-and-configuring-hibernate-orm-with-a-persistence-xml) as an alternative.

Comment: Is the behavior of injecting EntityManager into different Threads the same as in Java EE? In Java EE, injecting entityManager is a Proxy which is resolved to a free instance from the Connection Pool.  Does quarkus uses different entityManager for different Threads?

Comment: anyone famous with WildFly server can take a look on that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006162/how-to-color-the-log-of-wildfly-jboss-server-console-on-eclipse

Comment: @nimo23 that's the standard inject from CDI, so yes in a different thread you will have a different EntityManager by default; you could customize scopes with a custom producer: you can also inject an `EntityManagerFactory`.

Answer (score 3):

*persistence.xml* is supported, see [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#setting-up-and-configuring-hibernate-orm-with-a-persistence-xml)