# how to color the log of Wildfly - Jboss Server console on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logging, server, jboss, wildfly

I am using server **Wildfly version 18.0.0** and I want to **color the log** of my server while starting I am using Eclipse as IDE.
just like tomcat server Warn, Info.... How to do that?

[image: Console log of wildfly - Jboss server]

Comment: Did you try [LogViewer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/logviewer) and [Grep Console](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grep-console)?

Comment: how to change the location of my log from default to LogViewer ?

Comment: By default the pattern used for the console should log with colors enabled on the console. It's possible the Eclipse plugin removes the color, but I'm not sure. Is the console handler pattern the default pattern?

Comment: What do you mean with that "Is the console handler pattern the default pattern? " 
if you are talking about xml standalone config on JBoss somthing like that i have the default config i just added color-map attribut        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Coloring the Wildfly log in the Eclipse console

1. Install the [**ANSI Escape in Console**](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console) plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace :
   https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console
2. You may have to set or change the `-Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true` VM argument from Wildfly server launch configuration.
   To change it you:

   1. Go to the *"Servers"* tab
   2. Right click on the Wildlfy server
   3. Select `Open` menu entry
   4. In the displayed *Overview* tab, section *General information*, click on *Open launch configuration*
   5. In the *Edit Configuration* dialog, edit the *VM arguments* to change `-Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true` argument to `false`.

      On Linux you may remove the argument, on Windows you have to set it explicitly to `false`.
   6. *Apply* + *OK*

## About the color mapping

The default color mapping is as follow:

- error : red
- warn : yellow
- info : clear
- debug : green

Which gives the syntax `error:red,warn:yellow,info:clear,debug:green` .

The default color mapping is set in the [`org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.ColorMap`](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/37a099fe10f8afee54e61f56afb2891e7ce8c51c/core/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/formatters/ColorMap.java#L189) class.

### Color mapping sample

In standalone.xml you may set the mapping like this:

```xml
<formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
   <pattern-formatter color-map="error:red,warn:yellow,info:clear,fine:white,finer:green,finest:green" pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
```

Comment: @ManzMoody try out this solution

Comment: only removing `-Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true` didnt worked here,it was needed to pass `-Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=false` to make it works . JBoss eap 7.1 on windows 10

Comment: Answer updated thanks to @biguá comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can  define a **color map** to assign a color to different log levels.

The format is a comma-separated list of `LEVEL:COLOR`.

- **Valid levels**: finest, finer, fine, config, trace, debug, info,
  warning, warn, error, fatal, severe
- **Valid colors**: black, green, red, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white,
  brightblack, brightred, brightgreen, brightblue, brightyellow,
  brightmagenta, brightcyan, brightwhite

Launch the jboss cli cmd

- on Linux jboss-cli.sh
- on windows jboss-cli.bat

> location :
>   C:\FileLocation\wildfly-17.0.0.Final\wildfly-17.0.0.Final\bin

then enter this cmd :

```
logging/pattern-formatter=PATTERN_FORMATTER_NAME:write-attribute(name=color-map,value="LEVEL:COLOR,LEVEL:COLOR")
```

[source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/logging_with_jboss_eap)

Comment: I did exactly this, but my Eclipse console doesn't show any of the colors i defined in the color map. It still prints out all in one color. Any ideas?

Comment: @ManzMoody try out the new solution posted by Cédric